# what is "parameters" in scheme://netloc/path;parameters?query#fragment which returned by urlparse and where it is used?

Tags: python, url

https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-parsing

> Parse a URL into six components, returning a 6-item named tuple. This corresponds to the general structure of a URL: scheme://netloc/path;parameters?query#fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section 2.1 of RFC 1808 shows an example:

```
   <scheme>://<net_loc>/<path>;<params>?<query>#<fragment>

each of which, except <scheme>, may be absent from a particular URL.
These components are defined as follows (a complete BNF is provided
in Section 2.2):

   scheme ":"   ::= scheme name, as per Section 2.1 of RFC 1738 [2].

   "//" net_loc ::= network location and login information, as per
                    Section 3.1 of RFC 1738 [2].

   "/" path     ::= URL path, as per Section 3.1 of RFC 1738 [2].

   ";" params   ::= object parameters (e.g., ";type=a" as in
                    Section 3.2.2 of RFC 1738 [2]).

   "?" query    ::= query information, as per Section 3.3 of
                    RFC 1738 [2].

   "#" fragment ::= fragment identifier.
```

Section 3.2.2 of RFC 1738 deals with FTP URLs; I'm not aware of any other scheme that utilizes parameters. (Until 5 minutes ago, though, I wasn't aware of the parameter portion at all.)